# ARMA model in lavaan notation

Tags: autoregressive-models, r-lavaan

Like in the title, I'm searching for the AR(p) or MA(q) or ARMA(p,q) input for lavaan package which will be right.

I've already go trough some books, but I didn't understand how to do it completly right. Some book also is saying that parameters of autoregressive model change which isn't true for me.

```r
ar2_model <- '# Regresions:
              x3 ~ p1*x2 + p2*x1
              x4 ~ p1*x3 + p2*x2
              x5 ~ p1*x4 + p2*x3
              x6 ~ p1*x5 + p2*x4
              x7 ~ p1*x6 + p2*x5'
```

The ARMA(p,q) processes have also estimating errors which have 0 mean and the same constant variance for all of them which I think isn't described in the model